# Get a javascript variable's value in iOS app

Tags: javascript, ios, iphone, uiwebview

I need to access a javascript variable which is declared  inside a try block in the script

```
var ErrorResponse = "";
```

in my iOS app. I don't have much idea about javascript thats why I am unable to find out the way to do it. I am using this:

```
NSString *jsString = @"var temp = ErrorResponse; return temp";
NSString *myFieldValue1 = [self.viewYTParser stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:jsString];
```

to retrieve the value but it returns an empty string.

Comment: `var ErrorResopnse = "";` is empty. Set a value to it like: `var ErrorResopnse = "Foo";`

Comment: it is empty when it is initialized. It gets set with a value later in the code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the code that should do the magic:

```
NSString *errorResponse = [self.viewYTParser stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"ErrorResponse"];
```

Just execute this line each time you need to retrieve the up-to-date value of `ErrorResponse`.

You shouldn't use the `return` keyword.
If you want your JS to return any value from `stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString` then it should be something that you would regularly write **after** the `return` keyword in regular JS function - without the `return` word itself.

Comment: Are you sure that this variable has value at the moment you execute this line?

Comment: Yes. And just for checking I also initialized it var ErrorResopnse = "something"; but still didn't get anything

Comment: I figured out what the problem was. It was not accessible because it was declared locally. I declared it as a global variable and it worked. But now the trouble is that I am not supposed to make changes in the script and I will have to access the local variable. How can I do this?

Comment: Create a global variable and keep the local variable as it is. Assign value of local variable to global variable and then use stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString

Comment: @san Hi, I could have done it but as I said in comment above that I am not supposed to change the script.

Comment: You are not changing logic of the script. You are just creating another variable.

Comment: Guess thats the last option. I'll do it

Answer (score 0):

```
// simplified expression, no function needed
NSString *expr = @"document.getElementById('myDiv').offsetHeight / document.getElementById('myDiv').style.lineHeight";
// now pass it to the web view and parse the result
int lines = [[self.webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:expr] intValue];
```